# How to create Bestselller product and Related product and call it on the cms page in magento 2.2.0

Tags: custom, related-products, magento2.2.0, best-seller

I want to display Related products and BestSeller products on two different pages.

Comment: are u using the theme ? or default luma

Answer (score 0):

You can create a widget.

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-widget/

And add on cms